# Why AJAX Request Works With jQuery But Not With Fetch() Or Axios

Tags: jquery, ecmascript-6, fetch, axios

I'm working on something that needs AJAX calls. I want to code with the new ES6 API but it does not work with `POST` requests. I tried with jQuery and it works as expected. I don't know why the fetch() or Axios lib are not working and sending the `POST` parameters

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Handler: ES6 Fetch API
// Method:  GET Request
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
fetch('http://127.0.0.1/playground/server.php?handler=Fetch&method=GET')
    .then( response => response.json() )
    .then( data => console.log(data) )
    .catch( (e) => console.log(e) );



//------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Handler: ES6 Fetch API
// Method:  POST Request
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
fetch('http://127.0.0.1/playground/server.php', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        handler: 'Fetch',
        method: 'POST'
    })
})
    .then( response => response.json() )
    .then( data => console.log(data) )
    .catch( (e) => console.log(e) );



//------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Handler: jQuery
// Method:  GET Request
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
import $ from 'jquery';

$(document).ready( () => {
    $.get('http://127.0.0.1/playground/server.php', {
            handler: 'jquery',
            method: 'GET'
        }, (data) => console.log(data) );
} );



//------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Handler: jQuery
// Method:  POST Request
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
$(document).ready( () => {
    $.post('http://127.0.0.1/playground/server.php', {
        handler: 'jquery',
        method: 'POST'
    }, (data) => console.log(data) );
} );



//------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Handler: Axios
// Method:  GET Request
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
import Axios from 'axios';

Axios.get('http://127.0.0.1/playground/server.php', {
    params: {
        handler: 'Axios',
        method: 'GET'
    }
})
    .then( (r) => console.log(r) )
    .catch( (err) => console.log(err) );



//------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Handler: Axios
// Method:  POST Request
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
Axios.post('http://127.0.0.1/playground/server.php', {
    handler: 'Axios',
    method: 'POST'
})
    .then( (r) => console.log(r) )
    .catch( (err) => console.log(err) );
```

Comment: *"Not Working"* is not a proper problem description. What do the error handlers tell you? What troubleshooting has been done? What is or isn't working?

Comment: actually it does not show any error, it will send empty request!

Comment: Then explain all that in question instead of making us guess

Comment: I'm Sorry. You Are Right

Comment: You can edit a question at any time with clarification updates

Comment: It Does not work. I Will Try it on a remote server to test